# Why does Keras LSTM batch size used for prediction have to be the same as fitting batch size?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, lstm

When using a Keras LSTM to predict on time series data I've been getting errors when I'm trying to train the model using a batch size of 50, while then trying to predict on the same model using a batch size of 1 (ie just predicting the next value).

Why am I not able to train and fit the model with multiple batches at once, and then use that model to predict for anything other than the same batch size.  It doesn't seem to make sense, but then I could easily be missing something about this.

Edit:  this is the model.  `batch_size` is 50, `sl` is sequence length, which is set at 20 currently.

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(1, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, 1, sl), stateful=True))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=2)
```

here is the line for predicting on the training set for RMSE

```
    # make predictions
    trainPredict = model.predict(trainX, batch_size=batch_size)
```

here is the actual prediction of unseen time steps

```
for i in range(test_len):
    print('Prediction %s: ' % str(pred_count))

    next_pred_res = np.reshape(next_pred, (next_pred.shape[1], 1, next_pred.shape[0]))
    # make predictions
    forecastPredict = model.predict(next_pred_res, batch_size=1)
    forecastPredictInv = scaler.inverse_transform(forecastPredict)
    forecasts.append(forecastPredictInv)
    next_pred = next_pred[1:]
    next_pred = np.concatenate([next_pred, forecastPredict])

    pred_count += 1
```

This issue is with the line:

`forecastPredict = model.predict(next_pred_res, batch_size=batch_size)`

The error when batch_size here is set to 1 is:

`ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 1, 2) for Tensor 'lstm_1_input:0', which has shape '(10, 1, 2)'` which is the same error that throws when `batch_size` here is set to 50 like the other batch sizes as well.

The total error is:

```
    forecastPredict = model.predict(next_pred_res, batch_size=1)
  File "/home/entelechy/tf_keras/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 899, in predict
    return self.model.predict(x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
  File "/home/entelechy/tf_keras/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1573, in predict
    batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
   File "/home/entelechy/tf_keras/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1203, in _predict_loop
    batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "/home/entelechy/tf_keras/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2103, in __call__
    feed_dict=feed_dict)
  File "/home/entelechy/tf_keras/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 767, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/entelechy/tf_keras/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 944, in _run
    % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 1, 2) for Tensor 'lstm_1_input:0', which has shape '(10, 1, 2)'
```

Edit:  Once I set the model to `stateful=False` then I am able to use different batch sizes for fitting/training and prediction.  What is the reason for this?

Comment: Batch size doesn't work like what you describe, please add details and code.

Comment: Added errors and relevant code

Comment: If you're passing a batch with size 1, make sure it's still an array with the exact same shape as the training array, except that 50 becomes 1. Make sure you haven't lost one dimension transforming (50, 1, sl) in just (1,sl). It should be kept (1,1,sl).

Comment: @Daniel hey thanks for reply.  Yeah I've gone through it to check for correct dimensionality, I think it's all good as far as I can tell.  The error msg is ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 1, 2) for Tensor 'lstm_1_input:0', which has shape '(10, 1, 2)' anyway

Comment: I have faced the similar issue. But I found this link:https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-different-batch-sizes-training-predicting-python-keras/ really helpful. Life saving....

Comment: @McLeodx also try this [ten minute introduction](https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html)

Comment: Seems like this is not the case in new Keras (v.2.2.4-tf) and different batch size (1) can be indeed passed in to `predict()` method

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Unfortunately what you want to do is impossible with Keras ... I've also struggle a lot of time on this problems and the only way is to dive into the rabbit hole and work with Tensorflow directly to do LSTM rolling prediction.

First, to be clear on terminology, `batch_size` usually means number of sequences that are trained together, and `num_steps` means how many time steps are trained together. When you mean `batch_size=1` and "just predicting the next value", I think you meant to predict with `num_steps=1`.

Otherwise, it should be possible to train and predict with `batch_size=50` meaning you are training on 50 sequences and make 50 predictions every time step, one for each sequence (meaning training/prediction `num_steps=1`).

However, I think what you mean is that you want to use stateful LSTM to train with `num_steps=50` and do prediction with `num_steps=1`. Theoretically this make senses and should be possible, and it is possible with Tensorflow, just not Keras.

**The problem**: Keras requires an explicit batch size for stateful RNN. You must specify batch_input_shape (batch_size, num_steps, features).

**The reason**: Keras must allocate a fixed-size hidden state vector in the computation graph with shape (batch_size, num_units) in order to persist the values between training batches. On the other hand, when `stateful=False`, the hidden state vector can be initialized dynamically with zeroes at the beginning of each batch so it does not need to be a fixed size. More details here: http://philipperemy.github.io/keras-stateful-lstm/

**Possible work around**: Train and predict with `num_steps=1`. Example: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/lstm_stateful.py. This might or might not work at all for your problem as the gradient for back propagation will be computed on only one time step. See: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3669

**My solution: use Tensorflow**: In Tensorflow you can train with `batch_size=50, num_steps=100`, then do predictions with `batch_size=1, num_steps=1`. This is possible by creating a different model graph for training and prediction sharing the same RNN weight matrices. See this example for next-character prediction: https://github.com/sherjilozair/char-rnn-tensorflow/blob/master/model.py#L11 and blog post http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/. Note that one graph can still only work with one specified `batch_size`, but you can setup multiple model graphs sharing weights in Tensorflow.

Comment: Hey thanks for a really good reply.  Can you explain the difference between `batch_size` and `num_steps` again?  I've never actually used or seen `num_step` and thought `batch_size` was just how many windows are trained on at the same time.  What is the difference between a sequence and a time step?

Comment: For RNN models, the inputs are usually 3D tensors (batch_size, num_steps, num_features) meaning you train on multiple sequences in the same batch, each sequence have length num_steps, each num steps have num_features.

Comment: Here is a complete [short example](https://gist.github.com/tomzo/e0594f81220f57590521e32db0f9c530) on how to restore tensorflow model with LSTM cells when using different `batch_size` and `num_steps` than when it was trained.

Comment: What makes you think author meant `num_steps` not `batch_size`? Whilst your answer is related and somewhat useful, I think you're making a wrong assumption. If I'm not misreading something, they clearly speak about the various `batch_size`, not the `num_step` (which they refer to as `sl`). Other answers seem to provide better solutions to the specific problem author describes. Still, thanks for putting in the effort to write such a detailed answer!

Comment: @Hai-AnhTrinh Do you have link to blog post to implementation of rnn using tensorflow computation graph?

Answer (score 16):

Sadly what you wish for is impossible because you specify the batch_size when you define the model...
However, I found a simple way around this problem: create 2 models! The first is used for training and the second for predictions, and have them share weights:

```
train_model = Sequential([Input(batch_input_shape=(batch_size,...),
<continue specifying your model>])

predict_model = Sequential([Input(batch_input_shape=(1,...),
<continue specifying exact same model>])

train_model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam())
predict_model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam())
```

Now you can use any batch size you want. after you fit your train_model just save it's weights and load them with the predict_model:

```
train_model.save_weights('lstm_model.h5')
predict_model.load_weights('lstm_model.h5')
```

notice that you only want to save and load the weights, and not the whole model (which includes the architecture, optimizer etc...). This way you get the weights but you can input one batch at a time...
more on keras save/load models:
https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model

notice that you need to install h5py to use "save weights".

Comment: Oren I'm going to try that out, looks like a great solution!

Comment: Thank you for this.

Comment: Didn't work for me. ValueError: Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(4, 24), dtype=float32) must be from the same graph as Tensor("l1_1/kernel:0", shape=(4, 24), dtype=float32_ref).

Answer (score 7):

Another easy workaround is:

```
def create_model(batch_size):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(1, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, 1, sl), stateful=True))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    return model

model_train = create_model(batch_size=50)

model_train.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model_train.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size)

model_predict = create_model(batch_size=1)

weights = model_train.get_weights()
model_predict.set_weights(weights)
```

Answer (score 7):

The best solution to this problem is "Copy Weights". It can be really helpful if you want to train & predict with your LSTM model with different batch sizes.

For example, once you have trained your model with 'n' batch size as shown below:

```
# configure network
n_batch = len(X)
n_epoch = 1000
n_neurons = 10
# design network
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(n_neurons, batch_input_shape=(n_batch, X.shape[1], X.shape[2]), stateful=True))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
```

***And now you want to want predict values fewer than your batch size where n=1.***

What you can do is that, copy the weights of your fit model and reinitialize the new model LSTM model with same architecture and set batch size equal to 1.

```
# re-define the batch size
n_batch = 1
# re-define model
new_model = Sequential()
new_model.add(LSTM(n_neurons, batch_input_shape=(n_batch, X.shape[1], X.shape[2]),       stateful=True))
new_model.add(Dense(1))
# copy weights
old_weights = model.get_weights()
new_model.set_weights(old_weights)
```

Now you can easily predict and train LSTMs with different batch sizes.

For more information please read: https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-different-batch-sizes-training-predicting-python-keras/

Answer (score 2):

I found below helpful (and fully inline with above). The section "Solution 3: Copy Weights" worked for me:

[How to use Different Batch Sizes when Training and Predicting with LSTMs, by Jason Brownlee](https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-different-batch-sizes-training-predicting-python-keras/)

```
n_neurons = 10
# design network
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(n_neurons, batch_input_shape=(n_batch, X.shape[1], X.shape[2]), stateful=True))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
# fit network
for i in range(n_epoch):
    model.fit(X, y, epochs=1, batch_size=n_batch, verbose=1, shuffle=False)
    model.reset_states()
# re-define the batch size
n_batch = 1
# re-define model
new_model = Sequential()
new_model.add(LSTM(n_neurons, batch_input_shape=(n_batch, X.shape[1], X.shape[2]), stateful=True))
new_model.add(Dense(1))
# copy weights
old_weights = model.get_weights()
new_model.set_weights(old_weights)
# compile model
new_model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
```

Answer (score 2):

*I also have same problem and resolved it*.

In another way, you can save your weights, when you test your result, you can reload your model with same architecture and set `batch_size=1` as below:

```
 n_neurons = 10
 # design network
 model = Sequential()
 model.add(LSTM(n_neurons, batch_size=1, batch_input_shape=(n_batch,X.shape[1], X.shape[2]), statefull=True))
 model.add(Dense(1))
 model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
 model.load_weights("w.h5")
```

*It will work well*. *I hope it will helpfull for you*.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have **access** to the code that created the model or if you just don't want your prediction/validation code to **depend** on your model creation and training code ***there is another way***:

You could create a new model from a modified version of the loaded model's config like this:

```
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model_file.h5')
config = loaded_model.get_config()
old_batch_input_shape = config['layers'][0]['config']['batch_input_shape']
config['layers'][0]['config']['batch_input_shape'] = (new_batch_size, old_batch_input_shape[1])
new_model = loaded_model.__class__.from_config(config)
new_model.set_weights(loaded_model.get_weights())
```

This works well for me in a situation where I have several different models with state-full RNN layers working together in a graph network but being trained separately with different networks leading to different batch sizes. It allows me to experiment with the model structures and training batches without needing to change anything in my validation script.