# Keras hub text layer, with a sequence of documents to LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I would like to use a sequence of documents to predict a target label:

```
['some text here', 'some more text here'] --> label
```

Initially my text sequences are of a fixed length, which I am getting to work before trying to use a padded length. The architecture is as follows:

```
Input -> HubLayer -> LSTM -> Dense
```

The following code starts running and then fails:

```py
hub_model = 'https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-en-dim50/2'
hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer(hub_model, input_shape=(), dtype='string', trainable=False)

def build_model():
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(), dtype='string')
    inputs_1d = tf.reshape(inputs, [-1])
    x = hub_layer(inputs_1d)
    x = tf.reshape(x, [BATCH_SIZE,2, 50])
    x = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, activation='relu')(x)
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(y.shape[1], activation='sigmoid')(x)
    return tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

The problem is with how to pass a sequence to the keras hub layer (I believe).

Error:

```
2021-11-02 19:34:34.360697: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1680] Invalid argument: required broadcastable shapes
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_9371/20784351.py in <module>
----> 1 history = model.fit(train, epochs=2, validation_data=test)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1182                 _r=1):
   1183               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1184               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1185               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1186                 context.async_wait()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    883 
    884       with OptionalXlaContext(self._jit_compile):
--> 885         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    886 
    887       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    915       # In this case we have created variables on the first call, so we run the
    916       # defunned version which is guaranteed to never create variables.
--> 917       return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
    918     elif self._stateful_fn is not None:
    919       # Release the lock early so that multiple threads can perform the call

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3038        filtered_flat_args) = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   3039     return graph_function._call_flat(
-> 3040         filtered_flat_args, captured_inputs=graph_function.captured_inputs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   3041 
   3042   @property

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1962       # No tape is watching; skip to running the function.
   1963       return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
-> 1964           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
   1965     forward_backward = self._select_forward_and_backward_functions(
   1966         args,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    594               inputs=args,
    595               attrs=attrs,
--> 596               ctx=ctx)
    597         else:
    598           outputs = execute.execute_with_cancellation(

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     62     if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument:  required broadcastable shapes
     [[node gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/logistic_loss/mul/Mul (defined at tmp/ipykernel_9371/484917154.py:1) ]]
  (1) Invalid argument:  required broadcastable shapes
     [[node gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/logistic_loss/mul/Mul (defined at tmp/ipykernel_9371/484917154.py:1) ]]
     [[model_1/keras_layer_1/StatefulPartitionedCall/StatefulPartitionedCall/StatefulPartitionedCall/tokenize/StringSplit/StringSplit/_23]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_4634]

Function call stack:
train_function -> train_function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make sure that you provide both your sentences and labels during training and that both your input and output shapes are correct. Here is a simple, working example where the input contains two sentences and a corresponding label:

```py
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow as tf

hub_model = 'https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-en-dim50/2'
hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer(hub_model, input_shape=(), dtype='string', trainable=False)

def build_model():
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(2,), dtype='string')
    inputs_1d = tf.reshape(inputs, [-1])
    x = hub_layer(inputs_1d)
    x = tf.reshape(x, [BATCH_SIZE, 2, 50])
    x = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, activation='relu')(x)
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
    return tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

BATCH_SIZE = 2

sentences = tf.constant([
                         [
"Improve the physical fitness of your goldfish by getting him a bicycle",
"You are unsure whether or not to trust him but very thankful that you wore a turtle neck"],
["Not all people who wander are lost", 
"There is a reason that roses have thorns"],
["Charles ate the french fries knowing they would be his last meal",
"He hated that he loved what she hated about hate"],
["Charles ate the french fries knowing they would be his last meal",
"He hated that he loved what she hated about hate"],
["Charles ate the french fries knowing they would be his last meal",
"He hated that he loved what she hated about hate"],
["Charles ate the french fries knowing they would be his last meal",
"He hated that he loved what she hated about hate"]
])

labels = tf.random.uniform((6, ), minval=0, maxval=2, dtype=tf.dtypes.int32)

model = build_model()
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.losses.BinaryCrossentropy())

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
        (sentences, labels)).shuffle(
        sentences.shape[0]).batch(
        BATCH_SIZE)
    
model.fit(x=train_dataset, epochs=2)
```

```
Epoch 1/2
3/3 [==============================] - 1s 8ms/step - loss: 0.6965
Epoch 2/2
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.6916
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7fe851c4a090>
```

Your `LSTM` requires the input shape `(timesteps, features)`, so you need to make your `x` tensor of that shape. And your first reshape is necessary, because the `hub_layer` takes a batch of sentences in a 1-D tensor of strings as input.

Comment: Thanks! The code looks very similar to mine - not sure why mine is throwing errors. Just a side note, are the two calls to `reshape` absolutely necessary? Felt a little hacky to me...

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! but your code and mine is the same right - the actual model definition. So it seems the difference was that your dataset divided perfectly by the batch size, I have fixed this and my model is running!

Comment: Also the `predict()` function now expects the same `batch_size` as in training.

Comment: Yes, that is a side-effect of using a `LSTM` layer. Check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43702481/why-does-keras-lstm-batch-size-used-for-prediction-have-to-be-the-same-as-fittin)

Comment: Amazing thanks again for your help! I tried to find a input/output visualizer/debugger but I cannot find one, looking at the SO questions I think that it would be an useful tool!