# shapes (335476,50) and (3,50) not aligned: 50 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

my RNN is like this below

```
length_of_sequence = 3
in_out_neurons = 50
n_hidden = 128
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(n_hidden, batch_input_shape=(None, length_of_sequence,in_out_neurons), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(in_out_neurons,activation="linear"))
optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001)
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer=optimizer)
model.summary()

Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 lstm (LSTM)                 (None, 3, 128)            91648     
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 3, 50)             6450      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 98,098
Trainable params: 98,098
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

then try to train and predict

```
print(final_x.shape) #(165737, 3, 50)
print(final_y.shape) #(165737, 1, 50)
model.fit(         
    final_x,final_y,
    batch_size=300,
    epochs=10,
    validation_split=0.9
)
print(test_input.shape) # (1, 3, 50)
predicted = model.predict(test_input)
```

shows the error  `ValueError: shapes (335476,50) and (3,50) not aligned: 50 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)`

I am not sure wheere 335476 comes from....

Where should I fix ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually to use the same `batch_size` that you use to train your original model. More information on this topic and possible workarounds can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43702481/why-does-keras-lstm-batch-size-used-for-prediction-have-to-be-the-same-as-fittin). However, since you are using `None`, it should work with a single sample. Here is a working example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

length_of_sequence = 3
in_out_neurons = 50
n_hidden = 128
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(n_hidden, batch_input_shape=(None, length_of_sequence,in_out_neurons), return_sequences=True))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(in_out_neurons,activation="linear"))
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer=optimizer)
model.summary()

final_x = tf.random.normal((100, 3, 50))
final_y = tf.random.normal((100, 3, 50))
model.fit(         
    final_x,final_y,
    batch_size=2,
    epochs=10,
    validation_split=0.9
)

test_input = tf.random.normal((1, 3, 50))
predicted = model.predict(test_input)
print(predicted.shape)
```

```
(1, 3, 50)
```

Comment: However if you use `None` as your batch size you could use batches of any size both during training and inference.

Comment: mmm input size must be `(batch_size, 3, 128)`? I used `(165737,3,50)` for learning data though.... This aims to predict  next [50dimention], from three succession of [50dimention],[50dimention],[50dimention] items.

Comment: In my understanding in learning process train data shape is `(165737, 3, 50)` , then use `(1,3,50)` for predict purpose.

Comment: I added `model.fit()` in the article

Comment: Must have been a misunderstanding. Updated answer. Your code seems to work fine with the example I provided.

Comment: I tried your code and it works  
Thanks @AloneTogether I need to sort out the shape ideas.